# SocketTimeoutException instead of login error

Tags: android, jsoup, authenticator

I have this Authenticator:

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
            }
        });
```

And I use this to connect to a site:

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup
                            .connect("https://somesite")
                            .execute();
                    Log.d("STATUSCODE", res.statusMessage());
```

I can handle everything fine, except for the Login Errors. The **statusMessage()** always says ok, even if login credentials are wrong, and instead of setting statuscode to 401, it just throws a **SocketTimeoutException**. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `timeout` attribute:

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup
                        .connect("https://somesite")
                        .timeout(0)
                        .execute();
```